# VBA sorting column and reverting to original state

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to sort columns in excel by clicking on the column header and having it sort by descending order, and then when I click it again I want it to revert to the original state.

I have the code below that lets me sort by clicking on a column header, but I can only switch from ascending order to descending order, I'm not sure how to change it to get the column to revert back to its original state. All changes to try to do that resulted in different errors

```
Public blnToggle As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick _
   (ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   ' Updateby Extendoffice
   Dim LastColumn As Long, keyColumn As Long, LastRow As Long
   Dim SortRange As Range
   LastColumn = _
   Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), _
   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
   keyColumn = Target.Column
   If keyColumn > LastColumn Then Exit Sub
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Cancel = True
   LastRow = Cells(rows.Count, keyColumn).End(xlUp).row
   Set SortRange = Target.CurrentRegion
   blnToggle = Not blnToggle
   If blnToggle = True Then
      SortRange.Sort _
      Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
   Else
      SortRange.Sort _
      Key1:=Cells(2, keyColumn), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
   End If
   Set SortRange = Nothing
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the macro recorder. Turn it on, perform your steps manually with the Excel UI, then stop the recorder and observe the code it generated for you. There is no better tool for learning to write VBA in Excel, Word, and PowerPoint.

Comment: Please *indent* your code when posting.  It makes it much easier for us to read.

Comment: There is no sort setting for "original state": you would need to have your code store the original row order somehow (maybe in a different worksheet, possibly by just making a copy of the table before you sort it), and then restore the order from that stored information.

Comment: ...or add a column to the table where you can store the pre-sort row order.

Comment: What do you mean with *to it's original state.*? Show the data in the *unsorted* order you have before sorting? There is no such thing in Excel (there is, btw, no such thing in any database). If you need a specific order, you either have to remember the order manually or define a helper column that contains a sorting value.

Comment: @nicomp: You are right, except for PowerPoint. No Macro Recorder...

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick: Sort & Revert

- This will additionally highlight the header of the column that is sorted.
- If you save & close the workbook while a column is sorted, you won't be able to restore the initial order.

[image]

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private SortSequence As Variant

Sub SortData( _
        ByVal TableRange As Range, _
        ByVal Target As Range, _
        Optional ByVal SortOrder As XlSortOrder = xlAscending)

    Const SORTED_HEADER_COLOR As Long = vbYellow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, erg As Range, crg As Range, ecrg As Range
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With TableRange
        Set ws = .Worksheet
        rCount = .Rows.Count
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Set erg = .Resize(, cCount + 1)
        Set crg = Intersect(erg, Target.EntireColumn)
        Set ecrg = .Columns(1).Offset(, cCount)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    
    If IsEmpty(SortSequence) Then
        ecrg.Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & rCount & ")")
        erg.Sort crg, SortOrder, , , , , , xlYes
        SortSequence = ecrg.Value
        ecrg.Value = Empty
        Target.Interior.Color = SORTED_HEADER_COLOR
    Else
        ecrg.Value = SortSequence
        erg.Sort ecrg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
        ecrg.Value = Empty
        SortSequence = Empty
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Me.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = rg.Rows(1)
    If Intersect(hrg, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Cancel = True
    
    SortData rg, Target, xlDescending
    
End Sub
```